# What are the factors to calculate a timeout value for a test case in junit

Tags: java, junit, junit4

```
public class JUnitTimeout {
    @Test(timeout = 100)
    public void infinity() {
        //Some code to test
    }
}
```

what are the performance factors you need to consider to give a particular timeout value for a junit test case.

for example `@Test(timeout = 100)`  how can you give a value for the timeout in here it is 100

Comment: Why the image? Consider rewriting the code to text form. It will be searchable, editable, etc.

Comment: You can format text as code by adding 4 spaces at the start of the line. I see you already know how to inline code.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use `timeout` for regular unit tests. These tests run on different computers, with different OS's, and different amount of other processes running. Which in turn will make a small "hickup" fail your tests, and in many cases also your build (ant, maven). Setting a timeout close to what calling the method usually takes will only become a nuisance, halting a build seemingly at random.

What `timeout` could be used for is integration tests, that don't run at each build. For instance, if one has a non-functional requirement stating that a webservice should have no more than 2 seconds response time, a test with a timeout of 2 seconds that calls the actual webservice could be run before deployment of a new version, to make sure that the requirement is not broken.

Edit: Actually, I found a reason to use timeout on regular unit tests. I noticed some tests in my build taking a lot of time, turned out to be tests of what happened when a SOAP-client couldn't connect, and it was tested by trying to call an invalid URL. The problem is that there is a 20 second timeout, so each build got took a minute extra for three tests. I solved it through creating a `MethodRule` through, so the timeout can be added once for each class, rather than in each test-method. So, identifying tests that would slow down the build substantially is a use case for this. I'll set the timeout to 3-5 seconds, anything above this is probably taking an unecessary amount of time, and will be likely to slow down the build.

Comment: so i'm wondering why is it available on junit (unit testing framework) if we need it for integration tests and not in unit tests

Comment: jUnit can be used for making integrations tests as well.. Also, one could make a separate set of unit tests with timeouts that isn't run at each build (won't be worth it though in my opinion).